# Simple Java application not working

Tags: java

This pertains to a problem that I solved with far more elegant code. I was fooling around and trying to solve the problem in a different way using very basic code. The problem is that the number I am getting (2091059712) is not correct. The correct answer is 235146240000. This is driving me insane. Here is the broken code. I am trying to find the 13 adjacent digits within a 1000 digit number that have the largest product.

```
public class AdjacentProducts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = new int[] { 7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2,
                4, 9, 1, 9, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 9, 6, 7, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4,
                2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 9, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9, 6, 9, 8, 3, 5, 2, 0,
                3, 1, 2, 7, 7, 4, 5, 0, 6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 9, 5, 7, 8, 3, 1, 8,
                0, 1, 6, 9, 8, 4, 8, 0, 1, 8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 8, 8, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3,
                8, 5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 2, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5, 4,
                5, 9, 5, 0, 1, 7, 3, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 3, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 5, 3, 2,
                0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 7, 1, 5,
                8, 5, 2, 3, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 1, 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 9, 0, 9, 6,
                3, 2, 9, 5, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6,
                6, 4, 8, 9, 5, 0, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 7, 3, 1,
                8, 5, 6, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 8, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3,
                1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 0, 3, 0, 8, 1,
                3, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 7, 6, 6, 1, 4, 2, 8, 2, 8, 0, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                8, 6, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4, 9, 3, 0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2, 9,
                6, 2, 9, 0, 4, 9, 1, 5, 6, 0, 4, 4, 0, 7, 7, 2, 3, 9, 0, 7, 1,
                3, 8, 1, 0, 5, 1, 5, 8, 5, 9, 3, 0, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 0,
                1, 7, 2, 4, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 8, 3, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 7, 9, 0, 8,
                7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 9, 0, 1, 6, 9, 9, 7, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8,
                0, 9, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 3,
                6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 0, 9, 7, 5, 1, 2,
                5, 4, 5, 4, 0, 5, 9, 4, 7, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 4, 9, 0,
                7, 7, 1, 1, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 0, 4, 8, 3, 9, 5, 8,
                6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 0, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 9,
                7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7, 4, 0, 6, 4,
                9, 5, 5, 1, 4, 9, 2, 9, 0, 8, 6, 2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8,
                4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 8, 3, 9, 7, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 7, 5, 6,
                5, 7, 0, 5, 6, 0, 5, 7, 4, 9, 0, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 7, 9, 7, 2, 9,
                6, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0, 4, 7, 4, 8, 2, 1, 6,
                6, 3, 7, 0, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 9, 9, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 9,
                5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 5, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 7, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6,
                6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 4, 7, 9, 9, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2,
                9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 0, 8, 6, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 1, 3, 9, 1, 9,
                1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 1, 7, 8, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3,
                5, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2, 8,
                4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 4, 2, 6, 0, 7, 6, 9, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2,
                4, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 5, 5, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 0, 9, 3, 7, 0, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 0, 6, 9, 4, 1, 6, 5,
                8, 9, 6, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 9, 8, 4, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 9, 6, 2,
                4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 8, 1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 8, 7, 8, 7, 9,
                9, 2, 7, 2, 4, 4, 2, 8, 4, 9, 0, 9, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1,
                5, 6, 1, 6, 6, 0, 9, 7, 9, 1, 9, 1, 3, 3, 8, 7, 5, 4, 9, 9, 2,
                0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 6, 8, 9, 9, 1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6,
                0, 6, 0, 5, 8, 8, 6, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 4, 0, 5, 0, 7,
                7, 5, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5,
                5, 9, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 6, 2, 6, 9, 5, 6, 1,
                8, 8, 2, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 8, 2, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 0, 0, 8, 2, 3,
                2, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 7, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3, 4, 5, 0 };

        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 2;
        int d = 3;
        int e = 4;
        int f = 5;
        int g = 6;
        int h = 7;
        int i = 8;
        int j = 9;
        int k = 10;
        int l = 11;
        int m = 12;
        long result = 0;
        long largest = 0;
        while (m < 1000) {
            result = x[a] * x[b] * x[c] * x[d] * x[e] * x[f] * x[g] * x[h]
                    * x[i] * x[j] * x[k] * x[l] * x[m];
            if (result > largest) {
                largest = result;
                a++;
                b++;
                c++;
                d++;
                e++;
                f++;
                g++;
                h++;
                i++;
                j++;
                k++;
                l++;
                m++;
            } else {
                a++;
                b++;
                c++;
                d++;
                e++;
                f++;
                g++;
                h++;
                i++;
                j++;
                k++;
                l++;
                m++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What is the logic, please explain that in simple english, like the very part  you already explained. What needs to be done, what never worked out? sort of questions....

Comment: You're probably overflowing the ints. Try using longs instead.

Comment: why so many variables? just have one and manipulate as necessary better yet have a nested loop...also use x,length, not 1000...this code is not basic as it is not scaleable in any way

Comment: Why should it return that result? Is there a clear subsequence where that is the product? `x` just looks like a completely random array to me.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Hughes. Totally overlooked that. Will accept answer.

Comment: @Chris, It started out as a 1000 digit number. I had already solved the problem, but I was just trying to get an idea of how much faster my "elegant" solution ran compared to a non-optimal one.

Comment: @jarid.wade readability is always superior to performance when dealing with simple programs like this. If you were asked to constantly change the number of multiplied digits then you would have to spend so much time rewriting and reunderstanding this code

Comment: Why isn't the result simply to (histogram) list the quantities of each digit within the 1000 digit number, then multiple 9's then 8's etc.. until 13 digits are used?

Comment: @Logan Murphy Thanks. I understand the scalability issue. Like I said, I was throwing something together in an extremely rudimentary way in order to get an idea of any deficit in performance when compared to a far more acceptable program.

Comment: @jarid.wade and the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every multiplication is another chance for overflow. Your answer overflows before it ever gets put in `result`. One solution would be to change the definition of your array to

```
long[] x = new long[]
```

The same problem shows up in Puzzler #3 in the *Java Puzzlers* book:

```
public class LongDivision {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       final long MICROS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
       final long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        System.out.println(MICROS_PER_DAY / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
    } 
}
```

Here's the explanation Bloch and Gafter give:

> The problem is that the computation of the constant MICROS_PER_DAY *does* overflow. Although the result of the computation fits in a `long` with room to spare, it doesn't fit in an `int`. The computation is performed entirely in `int` arithmetic and only after the computation completes is the result promoted to a `long`. By then, it's too late.
>
> ...
>
> So why is the computation performed in `int` arithmetic? Because all the factors that are multiplied together are `int` values. When you multiply two `int` values you get another `int` value. Java does not have *target typing*, a language feature wherein the type of the variable in which a result is to be stored influences the type of the computation.

(Java uses target typing in certain contexts, in array initializers and now with lambdas, just not in general.)

The same text also points out that only the first value in the expression being multiplied needs to be a long, so you could keep the declaration of the array using ints and only change this line:

```
       result = 1L * x[a] * x[b] * x[c] * x[d] * x[e] * x[f] * x[g] * x[h]
                * x[i] * x[j] * x[k] * x[l] * x[m];
```

Comment: Huh?  x is an array of ints.  Why must it be set to long? At no time is any x value set to a product result.

Comment: @zipzit Because the multiplication of the indices of x is int multiplication which overflow at lower values as opposed to long values

Comment: @zipzit: good question, I looked up a very similar Java puzzler that explains this.

Comment: @NathanHughes.. Thank you for the edit / update.  That makes a lot more sense. `long_variable = 1.0L * int * int * int`  would have worked too?

Comment: @zipzit: yes, i tried it out just now. not 1.0L, just 1L